# Activator.CreateInstance() - Constructor not found

Tags: c#, .net, exception, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following class:

```
internal class MyQueryTranslator : ExpressionVisitor, IExpressionTranslator<QueryRequest>
{

       private IReflectionManager _reflectionManager;

       internal MyQueryTranslator(IReflectionManager reflectionManager)
       {
           this._reflectionManager = reflectionManager;
       }

       //....
}
```

Meanwhile, in another class, I am trying to instantiate this class using `Activator.CreateInstance()` method:

```
internal class MyPersistenceStrategy<E> : IAsyncPersistenceStrategy<E>
     where E : class, IPersistableEntity
{

       private IReflectionManager _reflectionManager;
       private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> _translators;

       static MyPersistenceStrategy()
       {
             _translators = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
             {
                  { typeof(QueryRequest), typeof(MyQueryTranslator) }
             }
       }

       private T TranslateExpression<T>(Expression expression)
       {
            if(_translators.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
                   throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("There is no translator for: {0}", typeof(T).Name);

            IExpressionTranslator<T> translator = 
                       (IExpressionTranslator<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(_translators[typeof(T)],
                                               BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                               null,
                                               _reflectionManager,
                                               null);

            return translator.Translate(expression);
       }

       //...

}
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type `System.MissingMethodException` occured in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Constructor on type `XXXXX.MyQueryTranslator` not found

As you can see, I am passing the appropiate `BindingFlgs` so the constructor can be actually found.

The `TranslateExpression<T>` method is being called like this:

```
QueryRequest request = TranslateExpression<QueryRequest>(expression);
```

I should also note that both classes are in the same assembly.

Comment: The code you've provided uses an overload of `CreateInstance` which.. doesn't exist. did you mean `new[] { _reflectionManager }` as the 4th parameter?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I can't believe that was it!! The overload actually exists, because it compiled correctly. Please post as an answer, so I can close this question

Comment: Weird. Clearly it is matching some overload. What is it doing in that case?

Comment: ah, I bet it is matching the CreateInstance(Type, params object[]) overload.

Answer (score 2):

As some have pointed out it is matching the wrong overload.
The parameters must be an array of objects.

```
(IExpressionTranslator<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(_translators[typeof(T)],
                                           BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                           null,
                                           new object[] { _reflectionManager },
                                           null);
```